program refuses to work with a single char
look at this pair of codes:
code with char as a string
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int loop, salto, salto_2;
    char caracter[2];

    printf("type how many loops you want?:");
    scanf("%i", &loop);
    printf("how often should it jump to a new line?:");
    scanf("%i", &salto);
    printf("type a character:");
    scanf("%s", &caracter);
    salto_2 = salto;

    while(loop >= 0){
        salto = salto_2;
        while(salto >= 0){
            printf("%s", caracter);
            salto--;
        }
        printf("\n");
        loop--;
    }
    getch();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

code with char as a single character
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    int loop, salto, salto_2;
    char caracter;

    printf("type how many loops you want?:");
    scanf("%i", &loop);
    printf("how often should it jump to a new line?:");
    scanf("%i", &salto);
    printf("type a character:");
    scanf("%c", &caracter);
    salto_2 = salto;

    while(loop >= 0){
        salto = salto_2;
        while(salto >= 0){
            printf("%c", caracter);
            salto--;
        }
        printf("\n");
        loop--;
    }
    getch();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

if i execute the code with strings it does work, but if i use a single char it will just skip execution and freeze.
using strings fixes the problem, i just want someone to explain me why does it not work with a single char, it seems like it should have worked, this is a University homework thing, that is why the code seem to have no purpose, it just prints a bunch of characters in the screen to test how while loops work, i asked the teacher and he just told me to use strings instead of chars.

it outputs on English now

Are you sure it's freezing, not outputting a bunch of newlines? (Which is, on first glance, what I'd expect it to do, consuming the newline after the second input as the character)

The first program uses the %s scanf specifier, which discards all whitespace characters (spaces, newlines, etc.). The second program uses %c instead, which does not discard whitespace. Therefore, this question is probably a duplicate of the following question: scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer

What is in the input stream after scanf("%i", &salto)?  If you are entering data interactively, it is almost certainly a newline, which will be written into caracter

what it does is like it skips the scanf("%c", caracter); causing it to print a bunch of new lines and then it "freezes" because of the getch(), i just want to understand why is it skipping the scanf() funtion

Your code is not skipping the scanf.  The scanf is executing and it is reading a newline character.  Try using a space in the format string and do scanf(" %c"...).  But, really, if you are trying to learn C just stop using scanf completely.  Attempting to use scanf while learning C is just an exercise is futility.  You will invest a lot of time learning scanf foibles, and that time is better spent on other things.

Or, when you are entering the data interactively, don't put the newline immediately after the 2nd prompt.  When the program asks for "how often should it jump to a new line?:", type "5Q" and see what happens.

I don't recommend that you use the function scanf for line-based user input, because scanf will generally not read a whole line at once. If you want to read one line of user input, I recommend that you use the function fgets instead and remove the newline character, if desired. In contrast to scanf, the function fgets will always read an entire line at once, if possible. See this guide for further information.

I have now marked the question as a duplicate. There is no need to delete it. However, you can delete it, if you want.

i will from on, thank you very much to you all for the answers.
